# Swapping SATA ports causes disk to click

Tags: sata, port, clicking-sound

I have a Dell XPS 8500. I swapped the drives that we're on SATA ports 0 & 1, and when I turned the computer on, the drive on port 0 made a clicking sound, and wasn't recognized by the BIOS. The other drive was fine.

When I switched them back, the clicking stopped and both drives were recognized.

Both drives are SATA 3, port 0 is SATA 3, and port 1 is SATA 2.

Can I not put a SATA 3 drive that was on a SATA 2 interface onto a SATA 3 interface?

This has nothing to do with a boot drive. This computer has an mSATA that it boots from.

Comment: Have you checked the S.M.A.R.T. data for the clicking drive? It could be on its way out and the slight physical movement pushed it over the edge temporarily. Or it could just be that the SATA data connector didn't make good contact.

Comment: @AndrewMorton My idea too. You typed your comment while I was writign my answer. (See point 3).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, you were absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 things come to mind:

1. Some sort of compatibility issue between the misbehaving drive and the SATA3 controller. It's rare, but not unheard of. Usually happens with early SATA3 drives or controllers that do not 100% implement the SATA3 spec correctly.
   No real solution to that, besides using another drive/controller.
2. Did you swap the power-connectors to the drives too? If you did the misbehaving drive might now be on a power-rail that is running on the edge of its maximum power-capability. This drive needs a little more juice than the other one and the rail can't handle the extra load. Try swapping some power-connectors around to see if that helps.
3. The drive is really dying, but it only causes issues on the SATA3 controller. On SATA2 it just doesn't show (yet), maybe because timing is less critical here. Put it back on SATA2 and check the SMART data. (It's also possible that the SMART error-log shows some other info that sheds more light on the problem while connected to SATA3.)

Comment: I'd peg 2. as the most likely

Comment: @Linef4ult Me too, with Andrew Morton's remark as a close 2nd.

Comment: Unfortunately, it was option 3. The drive had no issues until I put it on the SATA3 controller. Now it shuts itself off after spinning up to full speed. Thank you for the input.

Comment: @pbarney That sucks. Hope you've got a good backup.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the cable made a bad connection. Try it again and if that doesn't work, try cleaning the connector with a cotton swab.

As mentioned previously, you will probably want to check the S.M.A.R.T. data on your drive. When it starts clicking like that, there is trouble within the drive most of the time.

It could also happen that your SATA 3 controller or drive (or both) are early models that are not up to spec. Search up your controller model and see if others are having similar issues. Sometimes the manufacturer's website will also mention issues with the controller meeting standards.

Another option is to keep using it on SATA 2 until it fails, if the S.M.A.R.T. data shows OK.

Answer (score -2):

Your drive may be incompatable with the SATA 2 port. Is there an update available for your BIOS as this may resolve the issue

Comment: Poster mentioned explicitly both driver are SATA3 drives...

Comment: I think you meant "incompatible"... Still doesn't make much sense though, as the drive works fine in SATA2 mode.

Comment: *SATA 3 drives **cannot** be incompatible with SATA 2 ports.*

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Harvey, but a SATA3 drive will always work with a SATA2 port. I appreciate you taking the time to answer.